# Subtracting FloatVector from FloatVector using rpy2

Tags: rpy2

I am using [`grf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grf/grf.pdf) package in R in my Python code with the help of rpy2. However, I am a little confused with a structure that rpy2 returns.

Here I am trying to find the difference of two vectors simply subtracting. If it was just a vector in R, I would simply subtract using -.

But here is my problem:

```
    pred_w1.rx2("predictions")
    Out[92]: 
    R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
    <FloatVector - Python:0x1c17447e08 / R:0x7fe214bf7c00>
   [-0.548409, -0.224735, 0.948285, 0.269825, ..., 0.259327, -0.267804, 
    0.255273, 0.287592]


    pred_w1.rx2("predictions")
    Out[93]: 
    R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
    <FloatVector - Python:0x1c18f02808 / R:0x7fe214bf7c00>
    [-0.548409, -0.224735, 0.948285, 0.269825, ..., 0.259327, 
    -0.267804, 0.255273, 0.287592]
```

Now when I try to subtract like this:

```
    pred_w1.rx2("predictions") - pred_w0.rx2("predictions")`
```

I get this error:

```
    File "<ipython-input-95-161c70b4f42f>", line 1, in <module>
pred_w1.rx2("predictions") - pred_w0.rx2("predictions")
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'FloatVector' and 'FloatVector'
```

I think this should be fairly easy. I am just not so familiar with rpy2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegator `ro` (as in **r** **o**perator):

`pred_w1.rx2("predictions").ro - pred_w0.rx2("predictions")`

(more in the documentation: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#operators )